Export Docker Signature for Image
I am currently working on deploying signed Images.
I finally did it, but I want to export the signature.
But until now, I haven't known how to export an image's signature.
I already tried to export the image and search inside for the signature. I checked the documentation on https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/
but I still have no clue how to export the image's signature.
Is there even a way to export the signature of an image?
Maybe using the notary server of docker.io, when how do I get access to the notary server?
